# Make sure all files are uploaded to web server

Tags: javascript, file-upload, server

I have a list of files I need to upload, each is uploaded in a separate request.  How do I make sure that every file successfully uploaded, and that if any failed they all failed?  The code I am using to upload the files is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  upload(files[i]).then(function(d) {
    // success
    ...
  }).catch(function(d) {
    // fail
    ...  
  });
}
```

The server receives each file and saves it under a folder .  I want to make sure every file I send is uploaded successfully and if not delete all the files on the server.

Comment: you need to tell your server the total count and which one of the total your are uploading, then the server can decide if it needs to delete or move. you can tack on a GET param onto the upload POST if you have a sealed upload routine.

Comment: The server will be handling each request it gets from many users simultaneously, so how would the server know everything succeeded.  For example, lets say I upload 3 files, and tell the server I want to upload 3 files.  If only 2 files are uploaded the server will then just wait for the 3rd file even if it failed (user got disconnected for example).

Comment: it could wait, using a buffer flush or something, but that's a good point. it's easy to check for a problem if the server is told 3/3, and there's only one file in the temp folder, but if it's abandoned, things get murky. a simple chron job to delete any files older than 1 hour should cover you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you upload each file separately it s not possible for your server to know if all of them have succeeded.

What you can do is to inform your server at each upload for the next file to come.
By doing that you can keep a list on server side ( on a session / database / temp file ) with the files that have allready been uploaded and the next file in line.

If a file that is uploaded is out of order ( the previous upload had informed for a different file to be next ) then the server should abort the upload and rollback ( delete files based on the list you saved ) and return an error to client.

The only thing remaining in order for this to work properly is to take care for the case where the last K files fail to upload. In this case the server can not rollback by it's own so you have to inform it to rollback manualy. You can do that by creating a new request on your catch code. Like before when the server is informed that it has to rollback it should start deleting files from your temporary list and respond with error to your client.

If the client is disconected and can not send the request to server then your only solution is the use of cron jobs

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a perfect, hand-made PHP function for this - file_exists('filename'), which returns true or false depending on whether, well, 'filename' exists. You have to include the path from the root to the file if your file is being stored remotely, so in your case it would be file_exists('files/filename'). To check all the files at once, just use another for loop combined with some if statements (the following assumes PHP and predictable filenames):

```
$numOfFiles = numOfFiles;
$fileChecker;
$fileKiller;
$safeFiles = 0;

for ($fileChecker = 0; $fileChecker < $numOfFiles; $fileChecker += 1) {
    if (file_exists('files/file' . $fileChecker)) {
        $safeFiles += 1
    }
}

if ($safeFiles < $numOfFiles or intval(date('i')) % 60 === 0) {
    for ($fileKiller = 0; $fileKiller < $safeFiles; $fileKiller += 1) {
        unlink('files/file' . $fileKiller);
    }
}
```

Basically, this takes the number of files you're uploading (assuming it's foreknown), and runs a for-loop to verify that file[n] exists. For every file that has a verifiable existence, the counter ($safeFiles) increments by one.

If the count of safe files is less than the number of files, or the time is exactly divisible by sixty (indicating the hour mark), the files uploaded are progressively deleted through another for-loop, this one using $safeFiles as the upper bound. The deletion itself occurs by destroying file references through unlink().

There's some pitfalls to using the unlink() function, detailed over [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php); make sure to restrict the data targeted to one folder so that you have to delete the fewest number of references possible. Once the data escapes its box you could have exponentially more references to delete, and the function could become longer and longer as you delete more and more instances of individual files.

intval(date('i')) returns the time in minutes; when it's divisible by 60, the time is exactly on the hour, e.g. 1300, 1400, 1100, 0100, etc. This follows dandavis' suggestion to purge the server every hour, preventing muck from building up in the folder and confusing the system.

Of course, an alternative is to attach the data needed for the check/delete process to a session variable, and then attach the session data to dynamically created folders (deleted when a session expires). That way every user has their own personal checklist, and you can omit the chronometric deletion from your code. The downside to this is that it could be much more complex, especially if those files only need to be uploaded once in a given interval.

If you want me to explain the session-based solution, ask in the comments and I'll take some time to write it up; I won't do it now because it's obviously much longer than this solution and I'm not completely sure it's what you're looking for. If what I already wrote was enough, thanks for reading and good luck with your project! :)